# User Profile Picture not showing in SP2010 Feb2012 CU

Tags: my-site, user-profile-property

Environment: SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Edition, February 2012 CU

We didn't synchronise profile pictures with our Active Directory so far, but decided to change that. We tested it in our dev environment, and it worked. We tried it in our prod environment, and it doesn't work.

What we did was

- have a connection to ap.ourdomain, and a connection to all the other domains (uk.ourdomain, sa.ourdomain, am.ourdomain, ...)
- Add the User Property mapping Picture (SP) <- thumbnailPhoto (AD) (for both connections)
- ran an incremental sync, but later also full sync
- ran *Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -MySiteHostLocation mysite -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos $true* with the correct account (farm admin) (Note: mysite resolves to mysite.ap.ourdomain for us, for colleagues in Europe it resolves to mysite.eu.ourdomain, etc.)

Still, pictures don't show up for our users. We noticed that some pictures actually DO show up for users outside of ap.ourdomain who've got their photo in their MySite (so the PictureURL for colleagues in the US may be mysite.am.ourdomain/User Photos/Profile Pictures/....)

Is there any way to check if the photos are indeed imported from AD? Anything we did wrong?

**Update:** Checked in the FIM client, thumbnailPhoto is synced as seen in DS_FULLSYNC, but no photos show up in MOSS_EXPORT or mysite/User Photos/

**Update 4 June 2012:** Wanted to escalate it to external support today, and while preparing my email, I wanted to take screenshots of our setup. What can I say, the Picture<->thumbnailPhoto mapping was gone! It was still there last Friday (I looked at it in the late afternoon, and saw that mapping don't know how many times since we encountered this issue), but today there was no trace of it (no, nobody removed it). So we set it up again, ran a full sync, and this time it worked! I have no idea what happened, I can only say that it's working now as it should.

Comment: What LCID are your site running? Does images show in mysitehost/User Photos/Profile Pictures/ with the [userProfileManager.PartitionID]_[userProfile.recordId].jpg syntax after sync? How did you add the pictures to AD thumbnailPhoto?

Comment: LCIDs: 1033, 1046 (Portuguese Brazil), 1028 (Chinese Taiwan), 2052 (Chinese PRC). No images at all in the User Photos library, neither in the root nor in Profile Pictures folder. Not sure how pictures to AD are added.

Comment: And if you analyze the thumbnailPhoto property in ADSI Edit, do you see the hexadecimal string? Are your profile property set to import? Update-SPProfilePhotoStore only works if temporary images actually show in User Photos (with partitionid syntax). Does images show up correct in other apps like Lync and Outlook? If images are uploaded wrong (eg wrong encoding in PowerShell) or if image is of wrong type (eg GIF not JPG) it will seem to work, but SharePoint wont have it...

Comment: I don't have access to AD, so can't verify it with 100% guarantee, but we looked at it last week and I remember that the values looked ok.
Photos show up everywhere else without any issues (Lync, Outlook, SharePoint dev environment which has got the same patch level as prod)

Comment: We saw thumbnailPhoto with hexadecimal string showing up during the DS_FULLSYNC step. And image type should be ok, the wrong type should rather be the exception than the norm (at least my own profile pic has to be jpeg, as I provided it to our admin recently and he added it straight away)

Comment: Picture property is properly mapped and set as import

Comment: Since you have several languages installed, could you check that you are not hit by the Locale bug I mention here on my blog: http://andersrask.sharepointspace.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=7

Comment: No other folders inside User Photos

Comment: Unfortunately I have seen this with several other properties, not for Picture though: for no reason at all, the mapped property does not get updated.

Comment: Updated the info above, it's working now

Comment: I'd post your latest update as an answer and mark it as the correct answer just for good housekeeping's sake. Glad you got it worked out!

Comment: Haha, well never underestimate the power of Murphy ;-)

Comment: I believe it's Anders who helped Modery all the way through so he is deserving enough to take bounty!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 4 June 2012:** Wanted to escalate it to external support today, and while preparing my email, I wanted to take screenshots of our setup. What can I say, the Picture<->thumbnailPhoto mapping was gone! It was still there last Friday (I looked at it in the late afternoon, and saw that mapping don't know how many times since we encountered this issue), but today there was no trace of it (no, nobody removed it). So we set it up again, ran a full sync, and this time it worked! I have no idea what happened, I can only say that it's working now as it should.